# Snakemake input two variables and output one variable

Tags: snakemake

I want to rename and move my `fastq.gz` files from these:

```
NAME-BOB_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
NAME-BOB_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
NAME-JOHN_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
NAME-JOHN_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

to these:

```
NAME_BOB/reads/NAME_BOB.R1.fastq.gz
NAME_BOB/reads/NAME_BOB.R2.fastq.gz
NAME_JOHN/reads/NAME_JOHN.R1.fastq.gz
NAME_JOHN/reads/NAME_JOHN.R2.fastq.gz
```

This is my code. The problem I have is the second variable S which I do not know how to specify in the code as I do not need it in my output filename.

```
workdir: "/path/to/workdir/"

DIR=["BOB","JOHN"]
S=["S1","S2"]

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("NAME_{dir}/reads/NAME_{dir}.R1.fastq.gz", dir=DIR),
        expand("NAME_{dir}/reads/NAME_{dir}.R2.fastq.gz", dir=DIR)
        
rule rename:
    input:
        fastq1=("fastq/NAME-{dir}_{s}_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz", zip, dir=DIR, s=S),
        fastq2=("fastq/NAME-{dir}_{s}_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz", zip, dir=DIR, s=S)
    output:
        fastq1="NAME_{dir}/reads/NAME_{dir}.R1.fastq.gz",
        fastq2="NAME_{dir}/reads/NAME_{dir}.R2.fastq.gz"
        
    shell:
        """
        mv {input.fastq1} {output.fastq1}
        mv {input.fastq2} {output.fastq2}
        """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. First of all, the `{dir}` in your output and `{dir}` in your input are two different variables. Actually the `{dir}` in the output is a wildcard, while the `{dir}` in the input is a parameter for the `expand` function (moreover, you even forgot to call this function, and that is the second problem).

The third problem is that the `shell` section shall contain only a single command. You may try `mv {input.fastq1} {output.fastq1}; mv {input.fastq2} {output.fastq2}`, but this is not an idiomatic solution. Much better would be to create a rule that produces a single file, letting Snakemake to do the rest of the work.

Finally the `S` value fully depend on the `DIR` value, so it becomes a function of `{dir}`, and that can be solved with a lambda in input:

```py
workdir: "/path/to/workdir/"

DIR=["BOB","JOHN"]
dir2s = {"BOB": "S1", "JOHN": "S2"}

rule all:
    input: 
        expand("NAME_{dir}/reads/NAME_{dir}.{r}.fastq.gz", dir=DIR, r=["R1", "R2"])
        
rule rename:
    input:
        lambda wildcards:
            "fastq/NAME-{{dir}}_{s}_L001_{{r}}_001.fastq.gz".format(s=dir2s[wildcards.dir])
    output:
        "NAME_{dir}/reads/NAME_{dir}.{r}.fastq.gz",
        
    shell:
        """
        mv {input} {output}
        """
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a very good and clear explanation. I get this error nevertheless: Missing input files for rule rename:
fastq/NAME-{wildcards.dir}_S1_L001_{wildcards.r}_001.fastq.gz

Comment: I need to see the whole error message. Anyway, try to track down whether the file exists with the name that you would get replacing the wildcards with the values. My guess is that you've already moved it.

Comment: this is the whole error message. The files are present, I checked. It seems it is not reading wildcards.dir and wildcards.r?

Comment: I removed wildcards from both wildcards.dir and wildcards.r, and it seems to work now.